# Name of an old game about a spy infiltrating a fortress

Tags: pc, game-identification, third-person-shooter

I am going crazy trying to remember the name of a video game I used to play as a kid (I'm 35 now).

It was an old 2D platformer-shooter, with an eminently pixel-art style, where you played some sort of spy or special agent that infiltrates an enemy fortress located on an island. There were some puzzles in the form of locked doors and whatnot, and you had to avoid falling on traps such as a swimming pool with sharks, or some sort of electrified or laser traps.

I think the game was already old when I played it.

Other than enemy soldiers, the enemy that I best remember was dogs, perhaps mechanical dogs.

Upon completion of the game, you saw an image of the island exploding and the main character escaping on a motorboat.

I have asked ChatGPT already without success, but some of its suggestions where:

- Any game from the Metal Gear franchise
- Impossible Mission (1984)
- Flashback: The Quest for Identity (1992)
- Bionic Commando (1987)
- Elevator Action Returns (1994)

It's none of those.

I played on PC, and I believe it was not on a console emulator.

Any guesses? =)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, [ID of games from memory & without media from the game itself is considered off-topic here.](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10197/4797) We have a [list of alternative resources](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/4797) for such questions. Your question may also fall within the scope of our sister site [scifi.se] SE, which allows ID of games with a Speculative Fiction theme (Sci-Fi, Fantasy, and the like). Consider posting there, but check their [ID guidelines](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found it's **Secret Agent** (1992) from Apogee Software.

[image]

In game, it looked like this (notice the shark in the swimming pool on the left):

[image]

And the mechanical dog (bottom) and electric/laser trap (top right):

[image]

Well, I recommend it to everyone! Have fun! =)

Comment: I also have found that there were at least 3 releases of this game, named Mission One, Mission Two, and Mission Three. I can't remember which one I played but I'm guessing that it was the first one, as the title screens indicate this is the only one that is shareware.